# SQLite in-memory database not working with Microsoft Store

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am writing an application that creates and uses a (temporary) in-memory SQLite Database.  My local debug/release copies, as well as the ClickOnce version, work fine, but when I use the version deployed/downloaded from the Microsoft Store, I get an `unable to open database file` error.

This is my connection string:

`Data Source=InMemoryDB;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared;`

I imagine it might have something to do with SQlite creating a file on disk somewhere and then not being able to access it because it's in a protected folder?  But I don't know how I would specify (change) this since I am using an in-memory database.

Comment: run the app while monitoring with  procmon, this will show you every file it tries to access and what the result was (I dont think that in memory sqlite write to disk)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Doesn't look like [creation in memory](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

Comment: According to this it is - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/in-memory-databases

Comment: Try removing `;` after `Cache=Shared`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately doesn't change things...

Comment: Seems to be using a URI filename for this application.  I'm pretty sure it just uses it just uses the file on disk as a pointer of sorts - https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#:~:text=If%20two%20or,cache%3Dshared%22%2C%20%26db)%3B

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, implicitly, even though this is an in-memory database, SQLite still needs to create a dummy file somewhere for shared access.  It treats the `Data Source` parameter implicitly as a path to this file.  When a full path isn't specified, it treats this as the file name and tries to write to the local folder.

In the case of Windows Store, the app doesn't have write access to the local folder, and thus this file cannot be created.  Thus the solution is to specify a full path to a temporary file instead of just `InMemoryDB`.

```
public static string tempDBFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
...
var connString = $"Data Source={tempDBFile};Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared;";
```